# Extracting coordinate data from a FeatureCollection in csv within R

Tags: r, json, r-sf

I've got data currently within csv, with a column called "journeyroute." This column has the following data [truncated due to size]:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-4.095772, 50.409393]}, "properties": {"name": "start"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"name": "end"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[-4.095772, 50.409393], [-4.095781, 50.409397], [-4.095792, 50.409401], [-4.095965, 50.40971], [-4.096064, 50.410069], [-4.09597, 50.410397]]}, "properties": {"distance": 4027.4, "name": "Raw", "times": [1690900467000, 1690900520000, 1690900522000, 1690900539000, 1690900550000, 1690900569000], "duration": 4923.0}}]}
```

There are 5,000 rows of data. What I'm trying to do is extract out the LineString data to use within R, but I'm getting stuck. Can anyone help please?

I've tried converting to JSON and then unnesting, but comes up with an error (code adapted from other answers using Google Earth Engine):

```
new_df <- df %>%
    mutate(geo = map(Journey.Route, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(.))) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    unnest(geo) %>%
    filter(geo != "FeatureCollection") %>%
    mutate(coord = rep(c("x", "y"))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = coord, values_from = coordinates)

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `coord = rep(c("x", "y"))`.
Caused by error:
! `coord` must be size 5000 or 1, not 2.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Expecting a sf geometry column of LineString coordinates.

Comment: Consider including the data. ie `dupt(head(df))` in your question

Comment: I think @Onyambu means `dput(head(df))` to show the data. Edit your original post and then paste in the output of `dput(head(df))` or an example of what you're working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`library(geojsonsf)` can read a vector of geojson, so no need for any row-wise operations

- Create some data

```r
json <- '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-4.095772, 50.409393]}, "properties": {"name": "start"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"name": "end"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[-4.095772, 50.409393], [-4.095781, 50.409397], [-4.095792, 50.409401], [-4.095965, 50.40971], [-4.096064, 50.410069], [-4.09597, 50.410397]]}, "properties": {"distance": 4027.4, "name": "Raw", "times": [1690900467000, 1690900520000, 1690900522000, 1690900539000, 1690900550000, 1690900569000], "duration": 4923.0}}]}'

df <- data.frame(json = rep(json, 3))
```

- convert to `sf` object

```r
sf <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf(df$json)
```

- do any other operations you may want with the data

```r
## Remove empty geometries
sf <- sf[ !sf::st_is_empty(sf), ]

## Extract just the LINESTRINGS
sf <- sf[sf::st_geometry_type(sf) == "LINESTRING", ]

## Convert to a long data.frame
df <- sfheaders::sf_to_df(sf = sf, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Saw your earlier comment. Performance wise that's mighty-impressive boost,  ~5ms for 100 records on my setup. What put me off a bit is the difference in resulting pre-filtered sfc, for a single json  `paste(st_geometry_type(geojson_sfc(json_str)),collapse = ",")` returns `POINT,POINT,LINESTRING`, 2nd point being empty;  for a vector, `"geometry": null` in geojson suddenly turns into empty linestring, BUT only starting from 2nd geojson , i.e. `geojson_sfc(rep(json_str,2))` returns `POINT,POINT,LINESTRING,POINT,LINESTRING,LINESTRING`, 2nd point and 2nd last linestring being empty.

Answer (score 2):

As we are dealing with GeoJSON string, it can be parsed with `sf::st_read()` or perhaps with `gejsonsf::geojson_sfc()` for some performance boost (~ 2x when using geojson_sfc() as a drop-in for st_read(), ~ 100x when comparing rowwsie `st_read()` to vectorized `geojson_sfc()`).

Rowwise grouping to access one row at a time; keeping only `LINESTRING` geometries (presumably one per FeatureCollection, as in provided sample).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(geojsonsf)

json_str <- '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-4.095772, 50.409393]}, "properties": {"name": "start"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": null, "properties": {"name": "end"}}, {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[-4.095772, 50.409393], [-4.095781, 50.409397], [-4.095792, 50.409401], [-4.095965, 50.40971], [-4.096064, 50.410069], [-4.09597, 50.410397]]}, "properties": {"distance": 4027.4, "name": "Raw", "times": [1690900467000, 1690900520000, 1690900522000, 1690900539000, 1690900550000, 1690900569000], "duration": 4923.0}}]}'

# 100-row test sample
df_100 <- tibble(journey_id = 1:100, journeyroute = rep(json_str, 100))
df_100
#> # A tibble: 100 × 2
#>    journey_id journeyroute                                                      
#>         <int> <chr>                                                             
#>  1          1 "{\"type\": \"FeatureCollection\", \"features\": [{\"type\": \"Fe…
#>  2          2 "{\"type\": \"FeatureCollection\", \"features\": [{\"type\": \"Fe…
#>  3          3 "{\"type\": \"FeatureCollection\", \"features\": [{\"type\": \"Fe…
#> ...

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sf = {
    # parse GeoJSON strings with sf / GEOS
    routes_sf <- df_100 %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(geometry = st_read(journeyroute, quiet = TRUE) %>% 
                        st_geometry() %>% 
                        `[`(st_geometry_type(.) == "LINESTRING"), .keep = "unused") %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      st_as_sf()
  },
  geojson_sf = {
    # parse GeoJSON strings with geojsonsf
    routes_gj <- df_100 %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(geometry = geojson_sfc(journeyroute) %>% 
                        `[`(st_geometry_type(.) == "LINESTRING"), .keep = "unused") %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      st_as_sf()
  }
)
```

Benchmark results and resulting `sf` object:

```r
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>          sf 437.4351 453.1961 476.8028 464.1172 487.9901 628.0495   100  a 
#>  geojson_sf 198.3025 207.9465 219.1129 212.6965 221.7101 309.2461   100   b

routes_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -4.096064 ymin: 50.40939 xmax: -4.095772 ymax: 50.4104
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 100 × 2
#>    journey_id                                                           geometry
#>         <int>                                                   <LINESTRING [°]>
#>  1          1 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#>  2          2 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#>  3          3 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#>  4          4 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#>  5          5 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#>  6          6 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#>  7          7 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#>  8          8 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#>  9          9 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#> 10         10 (-4.095772 50.40939, -4.095781 50.4094, -4.095792 50.4094, -4.095…
#> # ℹ 90 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>